# On a post only one value from a select

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I'm working on a project where I require PHP and Mysql. I have a problem I haven't been able to solve, I obtain user input via HTML and PHP makes a query to mysql. I arrange data on a Select posting into it the `client_id`, and the Name of the client. However on the next page I'm trying to obtain data from the select, but only the `client_id`, not the name, so I can insert data using the id.

Here is my code in advance.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","usr","pw","table");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Clientes.cliente_id, Clientes.Nombre FROM Clientes WHERE INSTR(Nombre,'$nombre')");
echo "<form action='sumadb2.php' method='post'>";
echo "<select name='nombre'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option>";
echo $row['cliente_id']."-".$row[Nombre];
echo "</option>";
}

echo "<input type='text' name='saldo'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='agregar'>";
echo "</select>";
echo "</form>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

On the next page I'm trying to obtain just `$row['cliente_id']` using `$_POST` on php
how can I do this?

Comment: Use the ID as value on the option and name as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try with this,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['cliente_id']."'>".$row['cliente_id']."-".$row['Nombre']."</option>";
}
```

Comment: thank you very much I tried your code and it worked, the thing now is that i'm having problem displaying the name of the client, I only get the id number when I $_POST["nombre"], probably the correct question was how do I separate the variables so I can display the user where money was added any ideas?? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use value of Select Option

---

Corrected Code:

```
echo "<select name='nombre'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option  value='".$row['cliente_id']."'>>";   //**value added**
echo $row['cliente_id']."-".$row[Nombre];
echo "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

---

If you want to user this **ClientId** in next page you can use simply use:

```
$_POST['nombre']
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code in your while loop, or just take value as `cliente_id`

```
echo "<option value=".$row['cliente_id'].">";
echo $row['cliente_id']."-".$row[Nombre];
echo "</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input fields will be posted to the form action page on submit. So you can use the id as the value of the select options.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<option value='".$row['cliente_id']."'>";
echo $row['cliente_id']."-".$row[Nombre];
echo "</option>";
}
```